# Shall I create Unit test base

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wpf, unit-testing

Does it make sense of if I create a base test class of the same tests? What is the scenario in this case. For example I have almost identical viewmodels: XReport, YReport etc. and I create a base test:

```
public abstract  class ReportTestBase
{
    public T UC_ReportUserControl_Create<T>() where  T : class, IViewModel
    {
        return NinjectService.Get<T>();
    }
}
```

then I create derivatives:

```
[TestClass]
public class PsoriasisReport : ReportTestBase
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void UC_PsoriasisReportUserControl_Create()
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull(UC_ReportUserControl_Create<IPsoriasisReportUserControl>());
    }
}
```

These pieces of code are just samples. I am interested in methodology.

Comment: I would not do that. Test logic should stay as simple as possible.

Comment: Yes I know, but there is a huge redundant code. What is about with that

Comment: Anything that makes your life easier should be done. Unit tests are just code, and every technique of making the code readable and maintainable is appropriate.

Comment: We do this quite often to reduce copy paste. Therefor we implement abstract testbase classes containing helpers or common test methods. Abstract also avoids the unit test runner to execute the base test class as a separate testclass.

Comment: To your report base, add `public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }` as this is useful as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you have some commonality in your `[Initialize]` (`[SetUp]` in NUnit) methods, subclassing might be useful for test classes where you need the same set up over and over.

Beware the order that [these are called](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/densto/archive/2008/05/16/using-a-base-class-for-your-unit-test-classes.aspx) in MSTest.

Otherwise, I would create a hepler class as *Pragmateek* suggests.

Answer (score 1):

You could do that but as noticed by *StuffHappens* inheritance is maybe too much.

Can't you simply create a "*TestsCommon*" class with **static helper methods** to factorize all the redundant code?

I've already used this approach and it works well without making the code too obscur.